# Disable CCScrollLayer on a scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I got a scroll showing sprites, what I do is show put a background that disables all actions, except the CCScrollLayer...

Does anyone knows how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

To remove scroll, just disable touch.

```
mScroller = [CCScrollLayer nodeWithLayers:mLayerArray widthOffset:20.0f];

//In cocos2d 2.0
mScroller.touchEnabled = false;


//In cocos2d 1.0
mScroller.isTouchEnabled = false;
```